# Plotting Moving axis of realtime signal from arduino

Tags: matlab, arduino, matlab-figure, arduino-uno

I am new to matlab and I am finding it difficult to define an argument to plot a moving axis especially x-axis with xlim. I am getting a real-time signal from arduino and want to plot it against time. Look at my code below:

```
  clear all; clc; clf; 

  %a=arduino('/dev/tty.usbmodem1a12211');

  dt = 0.02; %sec. 
  %adjusted_dt = dt; 
  plot_window = 50;
  N_timesteps = 1000; 

  a = arduino('COM3');         
  a.pinMode(15,'input'); % z 
  a.pinMode(16,'input'); % y 
  a.pinMode(17,'input'); % x 

  a.pinMode(18,'output'); 
  a.pinMode(19,'output'); 

  a.digitalWrite(18,0);
  a.digitalWrite(19,1);

 x=zeros();
 y=zeros();
 z=zeros();
 t=zeros();

 %For Calibration.====================
 x_p_1g = 614.7500;  x_n_1g = 392.1351;
 y_p_1g = 612.6383;  y_n_1g = 387.7179;
 z_p_1g = 615.0000;  z_n_1g = 421.5684;
 %%%%%%%%==============================

 x_0g = (x_p_1g + x_n_1g) / 2.0 ;
 y_0g = (y_p_1g + y_n_1g) / 2.0 ;
 z_0g = (z_p_1g + z_n_1g) / 2.0 ;

 x_sntv = (x_p_1g - x_n_1g) / 2.0;
 y_sntv = (y_p_1g - y_n_1g) / 2.0;
 z_sntv = (z_p_1g - z_n_1g) / 2.0;


 elapsed_time_from_t_0 = 0.0; 

 %toc =0; 
 %tic; 

 for i=1:N_timesteps

 tic; 
 t(i,1) = elapsed_time_from_t_0;

 pause(dt); %toc;

 %  fprintf('dt = %10.7f;  (realtime dt)/(simul. time dt) = %5.2f  \n',dt, toc/dt);    

 %Simulation time is different from real time. 
 % t(i,1) = i*dt; % < = this is no longer valid. 


 x(i,1)=a.analogRead(3);
 y(i,1)=a.analogRead(2);
 z(i,1)=a.analogRead(1);

 %Calbiration  --------------------------

 x=(x(i,1) - x_0g)/x_sntv;
 y=(y(i,1) - y_0g)/y_sntv;
 z=(z(i,1) - z_0g)/z_sntv; 

 %Additional calibration code  --------------------------

 x(i,1)=a.analogRead(3);
 y(i,1)=a.analogRead(2);
 z(i,1)=a.analogRead(1);

 x=(x(i,1) - x_0g)/x_sntv;
 y=(y(i,1) - y_0g)/y_sntv;
 z=(z(i,1) - z_0g)/z_sntv;

 NEED EXTRA CODE/ARGUMENT TO CAUSE X AXIS TO MOVE/SHIFT TO PLOT THE LATEST 100 DATA

 clf;

 subplot(3,1,1); grid on; hold on;
 ylim([-2 2]);    
 xlim([ ]); need help
 plot(t,z,'b-o');
 xlabel('t[sec]');
 ylabel('z [g]');
 title('z');
 end


 subplot(3,1,2); grid on; hold on;
 ylim([-2 2]);
 xlim([ ]); need help
 plot(t,x,'b-o');
 xlabel('t[sec]');
 ylabel('x [g]');
 title('x');
 end   

 subplot(3,1,3); grid on; hold on;
 ylim([-2 2]);
 xlim([ ]);     need help
 plot(t,y,'b-o');
 xlabel('t[sec]');
 ylabel('y [g]');
 title('y');
 end
 toc; 
 elapsed_time_from_t_0 = elapsed_time_from_t_0 + toc; 

 end
```

Comment: Well I see one issue first: You aren't just plotting the last 100 pts of t,x,y,etc. All of your plot commands use the full vectors. Can you cut out every part of this that isn't relevant?

Comment: Thanks. But I actually don't want only the last 100 data. I want to view the 100 latest data as x-axis shift to accommodate the next 100-data dynamically.

Comment: I mean a moving x=axis as the plot grows to view the latest sampled data to like 100 (truncated data to show only the latest 100 at a time- meaning the previous 100 data at each time will not appear in the window)

Answer (score 0):

As you are plotting in a loop, plot is 'bad'. It reproduces the whole thing, while you only try to redraw a few points in it. What is better to do is the following:

```
h = plot(NaN);
for k = 1:N
  set(h,'YData',data,'XData',time);
  axis([time(k-100) time(k)+1 min(data)*1.1 max(data)*1.1]);
  redraw;
end
```

another option for the limits:

```
% symmetrical y limits
xlim([time(k-100) time(k)+1]);
if (k > 102)
  border = max(abs(data(k-100:end))) *1.1;
  ylim([-border border]);
else
  ylim([ min(data) max(data)]);
end
```

This method only replaces the data within the plot. The axis statement takes first x, then y limits. The lower limit (left, bot) is the time from before 100 samples, the right one +1 sec. I set min and max to be 10% higher/lower than max/min. Feel free to play here. 
For a full example using matlab/arduino with binary transmission of numbers (easier for arduino) see:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24368670/matlab-plot-serial-data-continously